# How to automatically change permissions and owner:group on any file added to a specific directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, slackware, chown

I run an unRAID server (unRAID is based on Slackware) and would like to find a way to automatically change the permissions and ownership of every file added to a specific directory.

Specifically, I would like to upload `.torrent` files from my laptop to a specific "Watch" folder on my server using SFTP. The problem is that the rTorrent docker container that is watching that directory is unable to load the uploaded `.torrent` files because their `owner:user` group is different from that of the container -- `root:root` for `.torrent` files sent via SFTP, and `nobody:users` for the container.

I suspect that the file permissions may also be an issue as the uploaded `.torrent` files have `0644` permissions and I believe that they need to have `0755` permissions. I've been able to get rTorrent to autoload these `.torrent` files by manually chown to `nobody:users` and chmod to `0755`, so I know that Autowatch works with these changes in place.

So, I am hoping that there might be a straightforward way to automatically chown and chmod every file added to this directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have another two way to reach your goal with built-in tools

- first you can use ACL

  - Here some reference how to use: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/usetfacl.htm
  - You can add in the default ACL of the folder your files are uploaded the user root:root with necessary permission.
- second one (and more elegant in my personal opinion):

  - Run the rTorrent docker container with UID match the UID own the files I find this page explain it well: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/usetfacl.htm

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment on SO yesterday, this is fairly trivial using inotify.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -x /tmp/watchy ]; then
  rm -rf /tmp/watchy
fi
while inotifywait  -e close_write -o /tmp/watchy --format %w%f  /path/to/watch
do
  found=$( tail -n1 /tmp/watchy | grep -E '.torrent$' ) && chown root $found
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I wanted the script to both chmod and chown would I modify it like this?


`#!/bin/sh
if [ -x /tmp/watchy ]; then
  rm -rf /tmp/watchy
fi
while inotifywait  -e moved_to -o /tmp/watchy --format %w%f  /mnt/cache/Downloads/watched
do
  found=$( tail -n1 /tmp/watchy | grep -E '.torrent$' ) && chown nobody:users $found && chmod 0755 $found
done`

Comment: Yes, that would do the job.

Comment: I had to change the `close_write` inotifywait event to `create` in order to get it to work with the uploaded files, but it's working great now. I also added the script as a "User Script" startup daemon (the unRaid equivalent of adding it to `/etc/rc.local`) so that it will run in the background all the time, since I quickly realized that the script would stop running as soon as I closed my ssh shell to the headless server.

Answer (score -1):

This may help: https://techarena51.com/blog/inotify-tools-example/

intotify can allow you to trigger a script when the directory is updated. The script could manage your chown and chmod on the fly.

Comment: The link is dead now...